# How to concatenate string_arr in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

How to concatenate  rcm_working_paper and documents code is below-

```
select  RCM.id as rcm_no,  
       string_agg(distinct RWP.body->>'working_paper_code', ',')as rcm_working_paper,   
       string_agg(distinct RWP.body->>'document', ',')as documents
from masters."RCM" RCM
  inner join  masters."RCM_WORKING_PAPERS" RWP on RCM.id=RWP.rcm_id
GROUP BY RCM.id
```

I am doing that way and occurred some error.

```
select  
    RCM.id as rcm_no,  
    string_agg(distinct RWP.body->>'working_paper_code'|| ' ' || RWP.body->>'document', ',')as 
    rcm_working_paper
from masters."RCM" RCM
  inner join  masters."RCM_WORKING_PAPERS" RWP on RCM.id=RWP.rcm_id
GROUP BY RCM.id
```

Comment: And what is the exact error message you get?

Comment: ERROR:  operator does not exist: text ->> unknown
LINE 3: ... RWP.body->>'working_paper_code'|| ' ' || RWP.body->>'docume...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 115

Comment: datatype is jsonb

Answer (score 1):

You need to enclose each expression in parentheses:

```
select  
  RCM.id as rcm_no,  
  string_agg(distinct (RWP.body->> 'working_paper_code')|| ' ' ||(RWP.body->>'document'), ',') as rcm_working_paper
from masters."RCM" RCM
  inner join  masters."RCM_WORKING_PAPERS" RWP on RCM.id=RWP.rcm_id
GROUP BY RCM.id
```

Alternatively use `concat_ws()`

```
select  
   RCM.id as rcm_no,  
   string_agg(distinct concat_ws(' ', RWP.body->> 'working_paper_code', RWP.body->>'document'), ',') as rcm_working_paper
from masters."RCM" RCM
  inner join  masters."RCM_WORKING_PAPERS" RWP on RCM.id=RWP.rcm_id
GROUP BY RCM.id
```

Or `concat()`

```
select  
   RCM.id as rcm_no,  
   string_agg(distinct concat(RWP.body->> 'working_paper_code', ' ', RWP.body->>'document'), ',') as rcm_working_paper
from masters."RCM" RCM
  inner join  masters."RCM_WORKING_PAPERS" RWP on RCM.id=RWP.rcm_id
GROUP BY RCM.id
```

Comment: @RAHULSONI if this answer solved your problem, please mark it as resolved.